# TP-LINK tl-wn727n installation

Tags: wireless

I have a TP-LINK tl-wn727n wireless adapter and have been trying to install it for nearly a week now. I'm new to Ubuntu and need help. If anyone could post an idiot guide on installing this thing I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That card needs an updated driver for its internal chipset, available from Ubuntu's repositories, for which you'll need to connect to your router via a wired network temporarily.

Unplug the wireless card from your machine, and connect your machine to your router with a wired network cable.

Wait a few seconds, and check you can browse to a website (e.g. www.ubuntu.com), to ensure you have a connection to the Internet.

To install the updated driver, click Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal, and type the following commands at the $ prompt, pressing Enter after each one and supplying your password if prompted:

Code:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-generic
```

Note when entering passwords the characters you type are not echoed back to screen, even as asterisks - this is normal Linux command-line behaviour.

When finished on the command line, type the following to close the terminal:
Code:
exit
Unplug your ethernet cable.

Close all your windows and restart the computer. This will make sure the older version of the driver gets unloaded from memory, so the new version can be loaded in its place.

When logged back in, insert your wireless stick.

Wait about 30 seconds.

Left-click the Network Manager icon on the panel at the top of the screen (it will be near the left-side of the clock) and you should see a list of available network names to connect to.

Click the one corresponding to your access point and you'll be prompted for any keys required to connect your network.

If you can't see any access points, right-click the network manager icon and make sure the option Enable Wireless is both present and ticked.

A message will appear briefly in the top-right hand corner of your screen when the connection is established.

Try browsing to a different website to check you have a working route out onto the Internet, and you should be all set.

In future, you should just be able to plug in the device, and if it doesn't connect to your access point automatically just left-click the network manager icon and pick the access point from the list.

SCR:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566639

Comment: thx for the qwik reply i appreciate it. I followed ur instructions all the way to the second code when i got this error. quiller_arc@Kaos:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-backports-modules-wireless-generic
Afterwards i did everything else u said but when i opened up the manager there r no networks and when i right-click it pulls up the same window as when i left-click.  from what can figure its some kind of bug but how to fix it i dont know.

Comment: Note that this is going to now be something like `sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic`

Answer (score 0):

saya sudah coba ikuti instruksi tersebut diatas, tetapi hasilnya seperti yang tersebut dibawah ini

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-generic
[sudo] password for personalia: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-backports-modules-wireless-generic
```